# Hiding the "top" part of the android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a requirement to show a keyboard input in an app I'm making, but the "top" part of the soft keyboard needs to be hidden. I say "top" part, I'm sure it has a name but I haven't been able to find it. Instead, I've drawn a diagram showing you which part of the soft keyboard I want to hide (the part enclosed in the red rectangle):

[image]

Is this possible? If so, could someone point me to the official docs that explain it because I've been unable to find any (probably because I don't know the name for the "top" part).

Comment: Is the embedded picture showing? It's not for me, but I'm pretty sure I embedded it correctly....

Comment: we are looking at what you are.

Comment: Ok, I guess imgur's servers are under heavy load or something. I'll attempt to explain. The area above the number row is the area I would like to hide.

Comment: image would be better. Are you talking about suggestions keyboard gives?

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can host it somewhere else

Comment: https://ibb.co/dFE0CA

Comment: No idea what's going on with the embedded image. If you click the link it loads fine, but for some reason it won't load when embedded on the question

Comment: This is what we were looking at before. Now I am confused. You "top part" looks like the edit text and that is not part of the keyboard.

Comment: No my edit text looks like: https://ibb.co/kLyrkV

Comment: that is a landscape mode of edittext enterring. It can be changed to the one used in portrait mode using `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` for EditText.

Comment: But it sure does look like part of keyboard. When I tap on edit text, that top bit slides up attached to the keyboard and covers my edit text... it appears to be part of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about the full-screen editing view (landscape mode).

Try to add

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
```

in the edit text

Comment: That did the job, so imeOptions is the key bit of docs I should have read!